# Outputting A Custom Blade Partial from Sober Controller

Tags: wordpress, roots-sage

So, for my template, I'm creating a block of code that runs custom "Modules".  Basically, they are a custom post type, with fields built in ACF.  Each of these modules has their own Blade template (e.g. /resources/views/modules/brandwindow.blade.php).

I've also created a Blade template for a custom post type called "Modular Page".  On this template, I handle all the calls for each and any module called in a loop.  I want to be able to handle this login in a controller, however.  So, I created a Controller called "LoadModules" that will handle that request.

I'm having some difficulty calling a Blade template from a Controller, though.  In a function GetModules(), I loop through the ACF repeater to see which module I need to load, and then supply all the relevant fields with another Controller specific to that Module (e.g. if module = 'bwindow', Call BrandWindow->BrandWindowFields).  This returns an array which I can then pass into a View.

I've added the View class to the top of the Controller (like you would in Laravel), but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong here.  I'm getting the following error:
    Class 'View' not found in ..\app\Controllers\LoadModules.php on line 25

Here's my Controller code:

> ```
> public static function GetModules()
> {
>     $brand_window_loader = new BrandWindow;
>     $module_array = get_sub_field('content_type');
>     if ($module_array == 'bwindow') {
>         // Do Brand Window Stuff
>         $windows = $brand_window_loader->GetBrandWindows();
>         $output = '';
>         foreach ( $windows as $window ){
>             $feild_array = $brand_window_loader->BrandWindowFields($window);
>             $output .= View::make('modules.brandwindow', $feild_array);
>         }
>         return $output;
>     } elseif ($module_array == 'blogfeed') {
>         // Do Blog Feed Stuff
>         return $module_array;
>     }
> }
> ```

Line 25, is throwing the error which is:

> ```
> $output .= View::make('modules.brandwindow', $feild_array);
> ```

The **$brand_window_loader->BrandWindowFields($window)** is just an array of keyed values it pulls from ACF using the ID of the post.

> ```
> 'title' => 'Title',
> 'sub_text' => 'Sub Text',
> 'url' => 'http://example.com'
> ETC.
> ```

The error is obviously related to the "View" class not existing, so I'm wondering if I've namespaced or the View class does not exist with Sage 9/Bedrock.  If that's true, what is the best way to include a Blade template from a Controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try :

```
$output .= App\template('modules.brandwindow', $feild_array)
```

Comment: Thanks, this was it!